# Gerar tabela de aquivos que foram realizados Upload

Tags: html5, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ASP.NET Core. E fiquei com algumas dúvidas, consegui encontrar alguns tutoriais de como realizar o Upload de arquivos pdf, mas, agora eu preciso que esses arquivos fiquem listados em uma tabela para o usuário visualizar posteriormente quando quiserem conferir algo. Como posso fazer essa visualização dentro da view ou em outra view. Desde já grato!!

Os arquivos estão sendo armazenados dentro de uma pasta na própria aplicação.

Essa é minha view index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<br />

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <section>
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Upload" asp-action="EnviarArquivo">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Enviar um arquivo :</p>
                            <input type="file" name="arquivos" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Enviar um arquivo :</p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Arquivo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Meu Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SistemaGR.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        //Define uma instância de IHostingEnvironment
        IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;
        //Injeta a instância no construtor para poder usar os recursos
        public UploadController(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _appEnvironment = env;
        }
        //Retorna a View Index.cshtml que será o formulário para
        //selecionar os arquivos a serem enviados 
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //método para enviar os arquivos usando a interface IFormFile
        public async Task<IActionResult> EnviarArquivo(List<IFormFile> arquivos)
        {
            long tamanhoArquivos = arquivos.Sum(f => f.Length);
            // caminho completo do arquivo na localização temporária
            var caminhoArquivo = Path.GetTempFileName();

            // processa os arquivo enviados
            //percorre a lista de arquivos selecionados
            foreach (var arquivo in arquivos)
            {
                //verifica se existem arquivos 
                if (arquivo == null || arquivo.Length == 0)
                {
                    //retorna a viewdata com erro
                    ViewData["Erro"] = "Error: Arquivo(s) não selecionado(s)";
                    return View(ViewData);
                }
                // < define a pasta onde vamos salvar os arquivos >
                string pasta = "Arquivos_Contrato";
                // Define um nome para o arquivo enviado incluindo o sufixo obtido de milesegundos
                string nomeArquivo = /* "Usuario_arquivo_" +*/ DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
                //verifica qual o tipo de arquivo : jpg, gif, png, pdf ou tmp
                if (arquivo.FileName.Contains(".jpg"))
                    nomeArquivo += ".jpg";
                else if (arquivo.FileName.Contains(".gif"))
                    nomeArquivo += ".gif";
                else if (arquivo.FileName.Contains(".png"))
                    nomeArquivo += ".png";
                else if (arquivo.FileName.Contains(".pdf"))
                    nomeArquivo += ".pdf";
                else
                    nomeArquivo += ".tmp";
                //< obtém o caminho físico da pasta wwwroot >
                string caminho_WebRoot = _appEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                // monta o caminho onde vamos salvar o arquivo : 
                // ~\wwwroot\Arquivos\Arquivos_Usuario\Recebidos
                string caminhoDestinoArquivo = caminho_WebRoot + "\\Arquivos\\" + pasta + "\\";
                // incluir a pasta Recebidos e o nome do arquivo enviado : 
                // ~\wwwroot\Arquivos\Arquivos_Usuario\Recebidos\
                string caminhoDestinoArquivoOriginal = caminhoDestinoArquivo + "\\Recebidos\\" + nomeArquivo;
                //copia o arquivo para o local de destino original
                using (var stream = new FileStream(caminhoDestinoArquivoOriginal, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await arquivo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
            //monta a ViewData que será exibida na view como resultado do envio 
            ViewData["Resultado"] = $"{arquivos.Count} arquivos foram enviados ao servidor, " +
             $"com tamanho total de : {tamanhoArquivos} bytes";
            //retorna a viewdata
            return View(ViewData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes utilizar o método `onchange` do input para executar um pedido AJAX ao servidor e retornar uma lista dos ficheiros que foram submetidos e gerar html para listá-los.
Algo assim (com jQuery):

```
$('#id_do_input').change(function () {
 $.ajax({
        url: 'GetUploadedFiles',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            // Gerar html com novo ficheiro submetido
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

E no MVC ter um método tipo:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetUploadedFiles()
{
    // return lista de ficheiros submetidos
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu acabei solucionando o problema de uma outra forma, já que os arquivos são estáticos, não mudam. Eu criei uma tabela com html e css, que faz referência aos arquivos que estão na pasta, gerando assim um link para exibição no próprio navegador. Isso resolveu temporariamente o meu problema, vou tentar aplicar essa opção que me informou.